# How to analyze a RC circuit with Integrated Chip in Parallel?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

I have a voltage source of 48 V, an IC and an RC Circuit between Vcc pin of IC and voltage source. RC Circuit is there to give a slow rise of 500 ms in the supply voltage of the IC (There is another long story why I am doing this).

I don't know how to analyze such a circuit to set values for resistor and capacitors. Following is a concept circuit.

How can  I  analyze this?

[image: IC with RC at Vcc for a slow rise in voltage]

Comment: It's quite rare that you would want a resistor in series with the supply pin of an IC. How do you define "very slow"? Microseconds? Milliseconds? Seconds? If you give us the datasheet of the IC, we can probably be of more help.

Comment: @BeB00 Thanks for such a quick response. The resistor is not for IC, it's just there to control charge time of the capacitor (or is it noob mistake?). By very slow I mean 500 Milliseconds (I will edit the question)
However, here is the IC - http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl494.pdf

Comment: There are multiple issues with your setup, but first of all, why do you want to have a slow rise time? Right now, I can tell you why it wont work, but without more information, I can't tell you how to make it work. This is a classic XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: How much voltage drop can you afford over the resistor? That determines the maximum value. From that you can calculate the capacitor. (Wikipedia RC circuit: "Time-domain considerations" is your friend)

Comment: Note: TL494 Absolute Maximum (damage) Ratings are violated, Operating supply voltage must be between 7V and 40V.

Comment: @BeB00 This is more of XYZ problem, it started with wanting to bootstrap a buck converter which is converting 48V to 5V(Which is the main supply for everything), then using a PWM generator IC and that went on to this (Let me know if I should mention more). But I would still want to know why this won't work(So that I don't make the same mistake in a different situation).

Comment: @Oldfart That's an interesting approach, gives me more constants. I will read up and see how I can apply "RC circuit: "Time-domain considerations"". Thanks!

Comment: @MarkU Thanks for pointing out, I am aware of that, that's what I am trying to solve.

Comment: Hey Vidit, you asked for feedback on your question: Don't ask for feedback in the question. We'll comment on it if we find there's something to comment on! Your feedback-asking, thanking in advance and saying you want this question to be good literally made your question twice as long as it needs to be, and that's not optimal for the reader who might want to answer it as quickly as possible, so I removed everything that's not relevant to the electronics problem, and it's still the same question :)

Comment: Why not use a zener diode instead of RC?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for the feedback, I will keep that in mind!

Comment: @Oldfart Is the Zener diode going to be okay for this? Will I need to put a resistor in the series? or putting a resistor can be avoided?

Comment: Just a zener diode to drop the voltage and it must be able to sustain 10mA. An LDO is better but but I think the zener comes closets to what you want: minimal components.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few reasons why this is a bad idea. First of all, 48V will break this IC anyway, but even if you use a different IC it's still not a great idea.

First of all, because of the resistor in series with the power supply, your supply voltage will be varying with the current draw of the device. This is almost always bad. Your capacitor will smooth that out, but it's still bad. In order to create a delay of 500ms (you don't define what you mean by "delay", and in this circuit, the "delay" will be a capacitor charging curve, as opposed to a straight line between 0V and 48V which is what you presumably want), lets assume you want two timing constants worth of delay. This means your RC should be 250ms (ignoring your supply current for a moment).

Lets assume you can tolerate a (very) generous voltage drop of 5V across your resistor, and your circuit only draws 10mA. This means your resistor should be at most 100 Ohms. In order to get a 250ms, your capacitor has to be 2.5mF. This is quite a bit, especially at 48V. The problem is that 10mA is just the maximum standby current at 15V. You don't know how much current it will actually take because:

1. The standby current can be anything, they just guarantee it will be less than 10mA at 15V
2. The current will increase as the voltage increases, as shown in the datasheet
3. This is just the standby current, and the actual current will also include the amount of current drawn by whatever your opamp is driving

This will lead to inconsistent and potentially unpredictable performance, which is bad. There is almost certainly a better way to do this, but we need to know more about what you actually want (you mention buck converters and PWM). I would recommend starting a new question with a description of your system as a whole, and what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out issues which I clearly missed.